# Log with carriage return in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea, logback, carriage-return

I had written myself a logging class which would not create line breaks in logging but log every status message onto the same line.
For this, I use the following code:

```
LOGGER.info(MarkerFactory.getMarker("no-linebreak"), "\r" + myLogInfo);
```

I then have a Logback appender which is only active when this marker is used and its pattern has no line break at the end.

This setup works when I run my application over the command line. It also used to work in IntelliJ Idea 2016. Now that I've updated to 2017.1, the carriage-return symbol \r does not seem to work anymore - the logging output is appended all in one line.

Any idea what changed in Idea 2017? Is there some console configuration I need to change in order for \r to work again?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `\n` instead of `\r`...

Comment: I've got the same issue here.

Comment: Somehow it works to instead log with a double carriage return \r\r...